# Creating Trie trees in TikZ

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm writing a Java app to generate tries for Latex using TikZ.

I'm struggling to typeset a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to follow example below:

[image: example]

Could someone provide me with an example how to properly nest children nodes and corresponding labels.

What I got now is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle] {}
    child{ node [circle] {} edge from parent node[above left] {$B$} }
    child{ node [circle] {} edge from parent node[above left] {$F$}
            child [circle] {}
        }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But edge labels won't match to the right edges.

Comment: We have plenty of tree questions on the site.  I would recommend using either `tikz-qtree` or `forest` for this.  See e.g. [How to typeset a prefix tree (aka trie)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61791) ; [How can I make Tikz tree node arcs not cross over each other?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174551) but if you look for questions involving either of those packages you will find plenty more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there are a number of questions with answers which label edges...

This might give you some ideas:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  circle,
  black,
  draw,
  fill=blue!40,
}
  [{}
    [{}, edge label={node [midway, above left] {B}}
      [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {A}}
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {U}}
          [,phantom]
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {E}}
            [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {R}}, label=below:Bauer
            ]
            [,phantom]
          ]
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {M}}, label=below:Baum
          ]
          [,phantom]
        ]
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [,phantom]
    ]
    [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {F}}
      [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {E}}
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {L}}
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {D}}, label=below:Feld
          ]
          [,phantom]
        ]
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [,phantom]
    ]
    [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {H}}
      [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {A}}
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {H}}
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {N}}, label=below:Hahn
          ]
          [,phantom]
        ]
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {U}}
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {S}}, label=below:Haus
          ]
          [,phantom]
        ]
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {O}}
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {F}}, label=below:Hof
        ]
      ]
      [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {U}}
        [,phantom]
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, left] {H}}
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {N}}, label=below:Huhn
          ]
        ]
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {N}}
          [,phantom]
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {D}}, label=below:Hund
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [{}, edge label={node [midway, above right] {K}}
      [,phantom]
      [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {A}}
        [,phantom]
        [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {T}}
          [,phantom]
          [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {Z}}
            [,phantom]
            [{}, edge label={node [midway, right] {E}}, label=below:Katze
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest tree]

Comment: So you typed! +1 for that :)